# Remove item from collection based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba

How do I remove an item from a collection, if that items (numerical item) is greater than a number, say 100.

My intention below:

```
dim XY as New Collection
 For Each Item In XY
                If XY.Item > Cells(11, 2) + Cells(12, 2) 
                                   'these two cells = 100 
                 Then XY.remove
```

Or is it not possible to remove things within the collection based on this criteria, and I'd have to paste it in excel and delete it from there?

Comment: Use a loop like `For i = XY.Count To 1 Step -1` then you can call `XY.Remove i` if `XY(i) > 100` Stepping backwards since you're potentially removing items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove Greater-Than-Items From a Collection

**The Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Removes all numeric items, greater than a value ('GTValue'),
'               from a collection ('coll').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub CollRemoveGT( _
        ByRef Coll As Collection, _
        ByVal GTValue As Double)
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = Coll.Count To 1 Step -1
        Item = Coll(n)
        If IsNumeric(Item) Then
            If Item > GTValue Then
                Coll.Remove n
            End If
        End If
    Next n
    
End Sub
```

**Utilization (Example)**

```vb
Sub CollRemoveGTTEST()
    
    ' Write some example values to an array ('CollValues').
    Dim CollValues() As Variant: CollValues = Array(101, "ABC", 99, 2, 100, 150)
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Calculate the criteria (greater than) value ('GTValue').
    Dim GTValue As Variant: GTValue = Application.Sum(ws.Range("B11:B12"))
    
    ' A reminder that 'Sum' fails if there are error values in the range.
    If IsError(GTValue) Then
        MsgBox "Error values found in sum range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Coll As Collection
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    ' Reference a new collection ...
    Set Coll = New Collection
    '... and populate it with the values from the array.
    For Each Item In CollValues: Coll.Add Item: Next Item
    
    ' Print before.
    Debug.Print "Before (" & Coll.Count & " Items)"
    For Each Item In Coll: Debug.Print Item: Next Item
    
    ' Remove the values greater than the criteria value from the collection.
    CollRemoveGT Coll, GTValue
    
    ' Print after.
    Debug.Print "After (" & Coll.Count & " Items)"
    For Each Item In Coll: Debug.Print Item: Next Item

End Sub
```

**Results (`SUM(B11:B12) = 100`) in the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)**

```
Before (6 Items)
 101 
ABC
 99 
 2 
 100 
 150 
After (4 Items)
ABC
 99 
 2 
 100
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to see, thanks for your time and effort